# Will getx automatically convert my string to the languages it supports

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I wanted to enable internationalization in my app. I am already using getx so i am going to use it to enable internationalization. However i had a confusion, in the getx page, there are these many languages that it supports. I was wondering if i would have to give a Translations class with the strings i want to only convert to these languages or would getx automatically do it for me. In other words, would i have to provide strings for these languages too, or will my text automatically be translated to these languages by getx

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These languages are available for Getx readme file and if you click on them you will see a readme in that language,

You must provide the translated strings to Getx material app.

You can use google translate, Excel, or this [VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=funkyremi.vscode-google-translate) to translate strings automatically